# Calculated Value with IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I never seem to get this right...
I have a date column 'Option1 and a numeric column 'Length'

The calculated date needs to be if Length = 1 add 7 days to Option1, if Length = 2 add 14 days:

The formula I places is:

```
IF[Length],"1",([Option1]+7), IF[Length],"2",([Option1]+14)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Length column in of type "Number", Use this formula:

```
=IF([Length]=1,[Option1]+7,IF([Length]=2,[Option1]+14,[Option1]))
```

Comment: Thanks For the help!!